# Want to Redirect back to index.php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

For my code below i am passing 4 parameter by using href method press from another page. With this, in this code, i use GET methods to receive all these 4 values and have them echoed under different values. However, when i want to go back to my index.php by pressing on the header, it does not direct me to the page. It directs me to bookingdays.php/index.php even though the right link that it should direct me is index.php. Please help me and thank you!

```
    <?php
       if($_GET != NULL){
    $price = $_GET['price'];
  $duration= $_GET['duration'];
        $car = $_GET['car'];
   $imgLink=$_GET['image'];
   }
   else{
header("location:index.php");
  }
 ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/CarRent.ico" >
  <title>Booking | Kereta Sewa Bajet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
     awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>
    .booking-box{
        width: 400px;
        border: 2px solid #2c3e50;;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 5% auto 0;
        border-radius:10px;

    }
    input[type="number"]{
        width: 160px;
        height: 30px;

    }
    input[type="date"]{
        width: 160px;
        height: 30px;
    }
    input[type="submit"]{
        width: 320px;
        height: 30px;
    }
    .btn-green{
        border-radius:10px;
        color: white;
        background-color: #27ae60;  
    }
    .btn-red{
        border-radius:10px;
        color: white;
        background-color: red;
    }

    body, html {
        height: 100%;
        line-height: 1.8;
    }

    .w3-bar .w3-button {
        padding: 16px;
    }
    input[type="text"]{
            width: 160px;
        height: 30px;
    }

  </style>

 </head>

 <body>

     <!-- Navbar (sit on top) -->
     <div class="w3-top">
    <div class="w3-bar w3-white w3-card" id="myNavbar">
        <a href="index.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-wide">KERETA SEWA BAJET</a>
        <!-- Right-sided navbar links -->
        <div class="w3-right w3-hide-small">
             <a href="login.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> 
               LOGIN</a>
             <a href="menu.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><img src="img/MYR.png" 
                 style="width:25px;height:25px;"> PACKAGE PRICES</a>
             <a href="#contact" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> 
           CONTACT</a>
             <a href="aboutus.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">ABOUT US</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Hide right-floated links on small screens and replace them with a menu icon -->
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-right w3-hide-large w3- 
       hide-medium" onclick="w3_open()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
     </div>

     <!-- Sidebar on small screens when clicking the menu icon -->
    <nav class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-black w3-card w3-animate-left w3-hide-medium w3- 
     hide- 
        large" style="display:none" id="mySidebar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-large 
           w3-padding-16">Close ×</a>
    <a href="#login" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">LOGIN</a>
    <a href="menu.php" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">PACKAGE PRICES</a>
    <a href="#contact" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">CONTACT</a>
    <a href="aboutus.php" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">ABOUT US</a>
    </nav>

   <script>
    // Toggle between showing and hiding the sidebar when clicking the menu icon
    var mySidebar = document.getElementById("mySidebar");

    function w3_open() {
     if (mySidebar.style.display === 'block') {
    mySidebar.style.display = 'none';
     } else {
       mySidebar.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }

// Close the sidebar with the close button
function w3_close() {
    mySidebar.style.display = "none";
  }
  </script>

     <header class="bgimg-1 w3-display-container w3-grayscale-min" style="padding:48px" 
    id="home">
     <div class="booking-box">
       <form action="#" method="#">
    <center><b>My Booking Details</b></center>
     <br>
     <center><img style="width:220px; height:140px" src="<?php echo $imgLink ?>"></center>
      <br>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Car</th>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="car"  value="<?php echo $car?>" id="car" readonly > 
                   </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Duration (Day)</th>
            <td>:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="duration"  value=" <?php echo $duration ?>" id="duration" 
                   readonly ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></br>Date Range</th>
            <td></td>
            <td><br><b></b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>From</th>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="date"  id="dateFrom"  min="<?php echo date ("Y-m-d", 
              time()+129600) ?>" onchange="calculateDate()" required></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <th>To</th>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="dateTo" onchange="calculateDate()" style= "width: 
                 160px; height: 30px;" readonly></td>
        </tr>                
        <tr>
            <th>Total Price</th>
            <td><br>:<br><br></td>
            <td><strong><input type="text" border="none" name="price"  value=" <?php echo 
                 $price ?>" id="cuba" readonly ></strong></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
     <center>
        <input class="btn-green" type="submit" value=" BOOK "><br>
        <input class="btn-red" type="submit" value=" CANCEL ">
    </center>
    </div>
    </form>
   </header>



<script>
    function calculateDate() {
    var date_from = document.getElementById('dateFrom').value;

    var new_date = new Date(date_from);
    var date_to = new Date(new_date);
    var day = document.getElementById('duration').value;
        if(day==1){
    date_to.setDate(date_to.getDate());
        }
        else if(day==3){
            date_to.setDate(date_to.getDate()+2);
        }
        else{
                            date_to.setDate(date_to.getDate()+6);
        }
    var dd = date_to.getDate();
    var mm = date_to.getMonth() +1 ;
    var yy = date_to.getFullYear();


    if(mm==1)
        mm = "Jan";
    else if(mm==2)
        mm = "Feb";
    else if(mm==3)
        mm = "Mar";
    else if(mm==4)
        mm = "Apr";
    else if(mm==5)
        mm = "May";
    else if(mm==6)
        mm = "Jun";
    else if(mm==7)
        mm = "Jul";
    else if(mm==8)
        mm = "Aug";
    else if(mm==9)
        mm = "Sep";
    else if(mm==10)
        mm = "Oct";
    else if(mm==11)
        mm = "Nov";
    else
        mm = "Dec";






    var someFormattedDate = '' + dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yy;
    document.getElementById('dateTo').value = someFormattedDate;

   }
  </script>

  <br>

    <footer class="w3-center w3-black w3-padding-32">
    <img src="img/BudgetLOGO.PNG" alt=""style="width:85px;height:25px;>
    <br clear="all" />
    <p>Owned by KSB</p>
    <img src="img/BudgetLOGO.PNG" alt=""style="width:80px;height:35px;> 
    </footer>

     </body>

     </html>
```

Comment: This sounds weird. You could try `location:/index.php` instead of `location:index.php`, but I can't be sure that `index.php` actually is in the root directory of the web site. Similary you could try `href="/index.php"` instead of `href="index.php"`.

Comment: it's worth checking your `.htaccess` files (if you're using apache) and make sure your web root is set up correctly. If you're unsure, post it in your answer and I'm sure somebody could take a look.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i solved it thanks! However, when i use url to pass parameter, my image(selected from folder) on the page does not show up.

Comment: Well then you probably didn’t specify the image paths correctly. So go and check what the browser console has to say, there’s probably 404s for those images showing up in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `location:../index.php` or `location:/index.php`. The former takes you up a directory to `index.php`, the latter brings you to the top directory then`index.php`